# Why is array.length giving "length" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in mapping?

Tags: solidity, arrays, struct, solidity-0.5.x

Here's how I defined an array of my struct:

```
  struct FoodItem {
     string name;
     uint price;
     bool available;
  }

  mapping(uint => FoodItem) public foods;
```

Now I want to delete an element from this array. Also, I don't need to maintain the order for now. For that, I did:

```
function deleteItem(uint index) public onlyOwner {
    require(index < foods.length);
    foods[index] = foods[foods.length-1];
    foods.length--;
    emit deletedItem(index, foods.length);
}
```

But it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: Member "length" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in mapping(uint256 => struct FoodOrder.FoodItem storage ref).
    require(index < foods.length);
                    ^----------^
```

I'm using `solidity 0.5.16` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an array. That's a mapping.

Mappings can't be iterated over and they are unordered - therefore they also don't have a length. In fact, there is no way to know how many entries a mapping has, unless you have stored that information somewhere else (or calculate it from outside the blockchain by looking at transactions).

To delete an entry from a mapping, you can simply `delete foods[id];`. Note that the `id` here is *not* an index, but the `uint` which you defined to be the key in the mapping.